# How can I check in nativescript unit that unit test is occur for iOS or Android?

Tags: android, ios, unit-testing, nativescript, nativescript-angular

While unit test in nativescript angular how can we check that this unit testing occurs for iOS or Android. I have written specific platform code so I want to test in unit test.

Comment: Have you tried settings environment variables?

Comment: @Olha I didn't try to use environment variables but how can I differentiate between platform is ios or android? If I am use environment variables then also I need to change when I test a particular environment.  I have written code that is run specifically environment. And I want to write a unit test for portion